# Convert left join query to Yii2 db active record

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have the following query:

`SELECT karyawan.* FROM karyawan LEFT JOIN user ON user.id_karyawan = karyawan.id WHERE user.id_karyawan IS NULL`

and I use db active record like this:

```php
$query = Karyawan::find()
    ->select('*')
    ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id_karyawan = karyawan.id')
    ->where(['is', 'karyawan.id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')])
    ->with('user')
    ->all();
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong with my db active record?

Comment: You don't need leftJoin here, eager loading `with('user)` is enough and it's default leftjoin.

Comment: it's still doesn't work, in yii2 debug the query become SELECT `karyawan`.* FROM `karyawan` WHERE `karyawan`.`id` IS null

Comment: if your `karyawan.id` is null then you have no reference with `user` according to your relation. That's why you can't get user details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is find all `karyawan` whose IDs are not referenced on the `user` table.

I think that what you are trying to do would be easier using this query:

```php
$query = Karyawan::find()
    ->where([
        'not in',  
        'id', 
        User::find()->select('id_karyawan')->column()
    ]
)
```

Use a sub-query to find all the `karyawan` IDs that **are** referenced in the user table:

```php
User::find()->select('id_karyawan')->column()
```

Then find `karyawan` whose IDs are not on the result set:

```php
where(['not in', id', $results])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is your primary key, you won't find anything because of

```
->where(['is', 'karyawan.id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')])
```

maybe you meant (find all users with empty karyawan)

```
$query = User::find()
    ->where(['user.karyawan_id' => null])
    ->all();
```

or other way round, like raul mentioned:

```
$query = Karyawan::find()
    ->where([
        'not in',  
        'id', 
        User::find()->select('id_karyawan')->column()
    ]
)
```

comments on query building:

```
$query = Karyawan::find()
    // ->select('*') // you can skip this
    // ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id_karyawan = karyawan.id') // this is done by 'joinWith'
    ->joinWith('user') // instead 'with', eager loading (LEFT JOIN), no extra selects on demand
    ->where(['karyawan.user_id' => null]) // shorter syntax
    ->all();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I'm exhausted and not aware with the "WHERE" syntax